# dynamic number of where condition in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic

I need to write a sql for a prompt in a reporting tool. I get the list of multiple values in a variable separated by '-' and the number of such values can vary.(eg1."abc-def" eg2."abc-def-xyz").

Now I need to write sql in oracle of this form(logically)

```
select something
  from somewhere
 where someColumn in 'abc' -- use substr to extract abc
    or someColumn in 'def' -- use substr to extract def
    or ...till we don't find '-'.
```

I can't use plsql for the query. Either I may not be knowing to use the variable in which I select into in plsql or may be the reporting tool doesn't support that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
select something
  from somewhere
 where someColumn in (select regexp_substr('abc-def-xyz','[^-]+', 1, level) from dual
                     connect by regexp_substr('abc-def-xyz', '[^-]+', 1, level) is not null);
```

To generalize (considering your fields are separated by "-")

```
select something
  from somewhere
 where someColumn in (select regexp_substr(variable,'[^-]+', 1, level) from dual
                     connect by regexp_substr(variable, '[^-]+', 1, level) is not null);
```

Basically the output of the subquery is shown below -

```
  SQL> select regexp_substr('abc-def-xyz','[^-]+', 1, level) value from dual
      connect by regexp_substr('abc-def-xyz', '[^-]+', 1, level) is not null;

VALUE                            
-------------------------------- 
abc                              
def                              
xyz
```

Answer (score 1):

First split the string into its parts using Oracle's regexp_substr() function.  See [regexp_substr function](https://blogs.oracle.com/aramamoo/entry/how_to_split_comma_separated_string_and_pass_to_in_clause_of_select_statement)  (If you can access the original that generates the string, just use that.)

Second, put this in a temp table and then just have:

```
select something
  from somewhere
 where someColumn in (select parts from tmpTable)
```

Comment: There's no need of a temp table, just an inline view is good enough. Also, it seems uneccessary in a reporting tool to populate temp tables (with user inputs) using PLSQL stored procs (which can be done anyways).

Comment: @Annjawn, I agree with you about the temp tables, but he is so new to this I wanted to keep it as simple and as testable as possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
select something
  from somewhere
 where INSTR('-'||'abc-def-ghi'||'-', '-'||someColumn||'-') > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a list of results that contain a '-', you could just do something like

SELECT SOMETHING FROM SOMEWHERE WHERE SOMECOLUMN LIKE ('%-%');

Comment: I have edited the question. Would you mind to take a look at that?