# pl/sql function- pass multiple varchar2 values dynamically for SELECT ... NOT IN()

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table `EMP` with following definition:

```
EMP_ID         NOT NULL   NUMBER(6)    
EMP_NAME       NOT NULL   VARCHAR2(25) 
EMAIL          NOT NULL   VARCHAR2(25) 
PHONE_NUMBER              VARCHAR2(20) 
HIRE_DATE      NOT NULL   DATE         
JOB_ID         NOT NULL   VARCHAR2(10) 
SALARY                    NUMBER(8,2)
```

If we want to count employees whose name not in 'King', 'Steve', 'John' we simply use this query :

```
SELECT count(*) FROM emp WHERE emp_name NOT IN('King','Steve','John');
```

---

**Now Here is what I want above this:**

What I want to do is, Create a `PL/SQL Function` which returns number of count according to the dynamic input, Like if we pass:

```
SELECT count_emp('King,Steve,John') FROM dual;
SELECT count_emp('William,Donald') FROM dual;
SELECT count_emp('Daniel') FROM dual;
```

needs to return appropriate count, how can I achieve this using `PL/SQL FUNCTION`

---

**This is what I have tried and Needs guideline:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION count_emp(emp_nm IN varchar) 
RETURN number
IS
  cnt      NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT count(*) INTO cnt FROM emp WHERE emp_name NOT IN(emp_nm);
  RETURN cnt;
END;
```

it is giving result for single name, but how can I split/format multiple input(i.e. `emp_nm`) to pass in `NOT IN()`?

Comment: you could get the string into a variable split it and then pass the list into the in clause such that you would have 'King','Steve','John' instead of 'King,Steve,John'

Comment: You can use dynamic SQL as well. There are plenty of similar questions on SO.

Comment: I.e. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12800180/pl-sql-comma-seperated-list-within-in-clause) and [another one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553398/dynamic-number-of-where-condition-in-oracle-sql).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use parameters in a 'where value in...' clause?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041647/how-to-use-parameters-in-a-where-value-in-clause)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
FUNCTION count_emp(emp_nm IN VARCHAR) 
RETURN NUMBER
IS
     cnt      NUMBER;
BEGIN
     SELECT count(*) 
     INTO   cnt 
     FROM   emp
     WHERE  ename NOT IN(
          SELECT regexp_substr (emp_nm, '[^,]+', 1, ROWNUM)
          FROM   dual  
          CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH (regexp_replace (emp_nm, '[^,]+'))  + 1);

     RETURN cnt;
END;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try dynamic sql:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION count_emp(emp_nm IN varchar) 
RETURN number
IS
  cnt      NUMBER;
BEGIN
  Execute immediate 'SELECT count(*) FROM emp WHERE emp_name NOT IN(' || emp_nm || ')'  returning into cnt;
  RETURN cnt;
END;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `MEMBER OF`. Here is a snippet. Hope this helps!

```
-- Create a type in SQL    
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_emp_name AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2 (10);

-- use MEMBER OF to use your list as IN parameter    
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION count_emp (emp_nm IN t_emp_name)
   RETURN NUMBER
IS
   cnt   NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT (*)
     INTO cnt
     FROM emp
    WHERE emp_name NOT MEMBER OF (emp_nm);

   RETURN cnt;
END;

-- Assign values to the list, you can do it dynamically as well. Call the function
DECLARE
   l_emp_name_list   t_emp_name;
   lv_count          NUMBER;
BEGIN
   l_emp_name_list := t_emp_name ('King', 'Steve'); --add more names as needed
   lv_count := count_emp (l_emp_name_list);
END;
```

Comment: This is just what I needed. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: glad to see that it was helpful!